# setOnClickListener is not working in my cardapter inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-cardview

Hi everyone I have an issue while making my cardview clickable inside a fragment, it's basically a recyclerview which have a cardadapter if we get a result the image would be clickable
here is my code, any help would be appreciated

**XML:**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"

    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_products_chosen"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/progress_product"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameproducts"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_products"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/imageurlproducts"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/priceitem"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/iditem"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Fragment code**

```
searchProductFromCategory fragment = new searchProductFromCategory();
    FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();


    FT.add(R.id.listproduct, fragment);
    FT.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    FT.commit();
```

**cardadapter:**

```
public class CardProductFromCategory extends RecyclerView.Adapter <CardProductFromCategory.ViewHolder>{

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    private Context context1;
    public ProgressBar progressbar1;

    //List of promoFeeds
    List<Products> PRODUCTS;

    public CardProductFromCategory(List<Products> product, Context context) {
        this.PRODUCTS = product;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_products, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new CardProductFromCategory.ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Products feed = PRODUCTS.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(feed.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

        holder.textViewItemName.setText(feed.getItemName());
        holder.iditemtextview.setText(feed.getIDitem());
        holder.priceitemtextview.setText(feed.getPrice());
        holder.imageurl1.setText(feed.getImageUrl());
        progressbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  PRODUCTS.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView imageurl1, textViewItemName, iditemtextview, priceitemtextview;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);



            this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_products);

            textViewItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameproducts);
            imageurl1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageurlproducts);
            iditemtextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iditem);
            priceitemtextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceitem);
            progressbar1 = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_product);
            //imageurl1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageurl);



            imageView.setOnClickListener(new  android.widget.AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   //code



                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

While debugging looks like I can't access to the setOnClickListener
Waiting for your answers guys :D

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_product_from_category, container, false);
    try {
        connectedUser = new getUserID().execute(mParam2).get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listcategory);

    getproduct(mParam1);
    CategoryFeed = new ArrayList<>();




    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);


}

private String getproduct(final String product) {

    //progressbar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_product);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    //progressbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    class getProducts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        // ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //  progressbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject JSONOBJ = new JSONObject(s);
                CategoryFeedJson = JSONOBJ.getJSONArray("Products");
                for (int i = 0; i < CategoryFeedJson.length(); i++) {
                    Products feed = new Products();
                    JSONObject json = CategoryFeedJson.getJSONObject(i);
                    feed.setItemtName(json.getString("ItemName"));
                    feed.setImageUrl(json.getString("image"));
                    feed.setPrice(json.getString("price"));
                    feed.setIDitem(json.getString("IDItems"));
                    CategoryFeed.add(feed);
                }
                context = getActivity();
                adapter1 = new CardProductFromCategory(CategoryFeed, context);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // loading.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("products", mParam1);
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            String result;
            result = ruc.sendPostRequest(Config.DATA_PRODUCTS, data);

            return result;
        }
    }
    getProducts uns = new getProducts();
    uns.execute(product);

    return product;
}



public class CardProductFromCategory extends RecyclerView.Adapter <CardProductFromCategory.ViewHolder>{

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context mcontext;
    public ProgressBar progressbar1;

    //List of promoFeeds
    List<Products> PRODUCTS;

    public CardProductFromCategory(List<Products> product, Context context) {
        this.PRODUCTS = product;
        this.mcontext = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_products, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new CardProductFromCategory.ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Products feed = PRODUCTS.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(feed.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

        holder.textViewItemName.setText(feed.getItemName());
        holder.iditemtextview.setText(feed.getIDitem());
        holder.priceitemtextview.setText(feed.getPrice());
        holder.imageurl1.setText(feed.getImageUrl());
        progressbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  PRODUCTS.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView imageurl1, textViewItemName, iditemtextview, priceitemtextview;
        public LinearLayout rl;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rl = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_product);

            this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_products);
            textViewItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameproducts);
            imageurl1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageurlproducts);
            iditemtextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iditem);
            priceitemtextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceitem);
            progressbar1 = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_product);
            //imageurl1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageurl);
            //imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String a,b,c,d;
                    c =imageurl1.getText().toString();
                    b = textViewItemName.getText().toString();
                    d =priceitemtextview.getText().toString();
                    a = iditemtextview.getText().toString();

                    uploadProduct (a,b,c,d);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try setting onClickListener in your onBindViewHolder() method

Comment: @Hass did you test the setting clickLiseneter in `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: yes I tried it, didn't work too

Comment: @Hass can you share whole itemview XML?

Comment: @Hass can you share also where you set the adapter in fragment whole code?

Comment: I edit the xml code however I didn't get your question about the adapter?

Comment: @TanveerMunir so any clue

Comment: @Hass can you change the CardView into relative layout and then click on it?

Comment: @Hass set the attribute `android:clickable="true"` for cardview

Comment: @Tanveer Munir didn't work too, I don't understand why? when I debug and put a breakpoint in here imageView.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){ nothing is happening

Comment: @Hass can you share you share the code of fragment code where you set the adapter.

Comment: did you try that using overall relative layout instead of cardview?

Comment: @TanveerMunir I just edited it in the end of my post

Comment: @Hass I didn't get what are you exactly doing in your code that's the partial code which you post.

Comment: @TanveerMunir it's a fragment that comes after we type a product category, the list of products come in a fragment and we suppose to select this product from the list that come in a recyclerview in the fragment

Comment: Possibly you are right but you post that code which does not clarify for anyone so please share your code separately like first, you share fragment code then adapter code whole files...

Answer (score 0):

### Edited:

Set attributes in XML file for your `<ImageView>`

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

It will work.

---

I think you have problem in implementing Listener.

You can change

```
View.OnClickListener
```

instead of

```
android.widget.AdapterView.OnClickListener
```

### Edit:

**USE This One:**

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code
    }
 });
```

## Instead of this :

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new  android.widget.AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code
    }
 });
```

Hope it will work for you.

Thank you.

Comment: I was using both way View.OnClickListener and android.widget.AdapterView.OnClickListener and both are not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

      ViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
       }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

pos  - position of row clicked

Answer (score 0):

Set the `setOnClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder`

**Like this:**

```
 holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the wrong references in your ViewHolder for your Views.Correct them like this if given xml code is for `item_products` xml.

```
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_products_list);

        textViewItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameproducts_list);
        imageurl1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageurlproducts);
        iditemtextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iditem);
        priceitemtextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_list);
        progressbar1 = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in viewholder:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //TODO...
            }
        });
```